# Draw line using its angle and radius in iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to draw line from one point to another unknown point.I want to find this unknown point using its angle and radius from current point. Then i want to draw between these two points as line..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Note:

I already used these method

```
x2 = x1 - length * cos(angle)
y2 = y1 - length * sin(angle)
```

But these found point is not correct for some angle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. The use of `-` and `+` after `... = x1` and `... = y1` depends on the angular coordinate system you want to use. Make sure you've got this right.
2. Likewise `cos` and `sin` may need to be swapped.
3. Is `angle` in radians? If it's in degrees, it won't work.

Note that I'm not suggesting you have points 1 and 2 wrong. It's impossible to say without knowing how you want your geometry to function, and what coordinate system you're using. Plus, the iPhone SDKs are a bit schizophrenic in this regard.

Comment: sorry,Its my mistake.. I use this mainly for find mirror point of triangle.(Its working fine) For some distance my triangle changes to trapezoid . Can you tell me how to find mirror point of trapezoid ?